# Unity - how to force rigid bodies out of the visible screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I need to know if there is an established way to do this, given that what defines screen boundaries depends on the device, etc. I have these rigid bodies that are not kinematic and not affected by gravity with light masses. When I instantiate them, they are all in an empty with a sphere overlapping them to create an "explosion" effect.

This works well, however after the sphere pushes the rigid bodies apart and explosion has occurred, I need the bodies to ALL keep moving until out of the users view/the screen. This happens for most of them but they are some stragglers and some take a very long time, staying in center of the screen.

I would normally apply a force but I do not know for each rigid body (there are a lot) which way they would need to move depending on where they are.

How can I apply a force that gets all these rigdibodies off the screen? The explosion is supposed to be in all directions. Is there a certain Vector that would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Project the position of the object onto the camera's facing vector.  And then make a vector from the projected point, back to the object.

So, something like..

```
    var t = Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, obj.transform.position); //distance along view vector
    var p = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * t; // position along view direction
    var d = obj.transform.position - p; //vector from center to object
```

Comment: Ok I will try this - I have a perspective side view camera set up though - are you sure this won't bring the rigid bodies towards the camera instead of out?